# Return constructor of generic type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm struggling to define how to write TypeScipt code which says that function return constructor of generic type. There are plenty of examples around about how to pass constructor of the generic type, but not how to return.

Please check the following example:

This is part of the abstract class:

```
 getModel():  (new () => T) {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.'); // Error because don't know how to fix it
}
```

When in derived class I'm trying to implement it like this:

```
getModel(): typeof User {
    return User;
}
```

I have the following error:

```
Type '() => typeof User' is not assignable to type '() => new () => User'.
```

I could skip implementation in the derived class if I knew how to specify in the abstract class.

So question is - how to specify on an abstract class level that method returns constructor of the generic type and I can skip implementation of this method at child level class? Or maybe I specify return signature not correctly on the abstract class level?

**EDIT:**

Please check the strange problem. Class A and B differ only by the presence of explicit constructor. And in RealA doesn't work and RealB works the same getModel() method.

```
class A {
a = '';
constructor(a: string) {

}
}

class B {
    a = '';
    static test(): void {
        console.log('I do work');
    }
}

abstract class Base<T> {
    Prop: T;
    constructor(TCreator: { new (): T; }) {
        this.Prop = new TCreator();
    }

    getModel(): (new () => T) {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.'); // Error because don't know how to fix it
    }
}

class RealA extends Base<A> {
    getModel(): typeof A { // doesn't work - compilation error
        return A;
    }
}

class RealB extends Base<B> {
    getModel(): typeof B { // works
        return B;
    }
}

var test = new RealA(A); // compile error
var test2 = new RealB(B)
```

For RealA class the same error

```
() => typeof A' is not assignable to type '() => new () => A'
```

Comment: Could you post a full example. Seems to work with what you provided : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20User%20%7B%20private%20x%3Astring%7D%0D%0Aclass%20A%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getModel()%3A%20(new%20()%20%3D%3E%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error('Method%20not%20implemented.')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%20because%20don't%20know%20how%20to%20fix%20it%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%3CUser%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getModel()%3A%20typeof%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20User%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: Looks like your `T` is the constructor type and not the instance type for some reason.  Note that the type `User` and the value `User` are different and that the type `typeof User` is not the same as the type `User`.  You should post a [mcve] for someone to pinpoint the issue exactly.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  please check initial question. I updated it.

Comment: Not sure what's the use case, but as a side note - you can just have `getModel() { return this.constructor; }` in the base instead of implementing it in each derived class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is expected as the constructor for class `A` has a required argument. The abstract class constrains the constructor to be passed it to have no arguments (`new () => T`).

The simple solution is to remove the constructor to `A`.

If you want to be able to pass in classes that have constructors that require arguments you will need to change the definition of the base class to capture the constructor type, and have the `constructor` take in those required arguments (using tuples in [rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897))

```
class A {
    a = '';
    constructor(a: string) {

    }
}

class B {
    a = '';
    static test(): void {
        console.log('I do work');
    }
}

type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends new (...a: infer A) => any? A : [] 
abstract class Base<T extends new (...a: any[])=> any> {
    Prop: InstanceType<T>;
    constructor(TCreator: T, ...a: ArgumentTypes<T>) {
        this.Prop = new TCreator(...a);
    }

    getModel(): T {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.'); // Error because don't know how to fix it
    }
}

class RealA extends Base<typeof A> {
    getModel(): typeof A { // doesn't work - compilation error
        return A;
    }
}

class RealB extends Base<typeof B> {
    getModel(): typeof B { // works
        return B;
    }
}

var test = new RealA(A, ""); // ok
var test2 = new RealB(B)
```

Comment: Now it makes a lot of sense. How would be easier if they put this error or similar explanation? Thank you a lot. Will think about the solution. Both of them probably not applicable because we can't use **any**.

Comment: @Selvatico in this case `any` is just a placeholder, it's all fully type safe, the `any` will not leak into the public signature of the class or the implementation. It's just there to tell the compiler the constructor can return any class and can have any number of arguments of any type. When you pass in a class, the class wil decide the arguments and the instance type and no any will actually exist. Let me know if I can help any further :)